# Discover the linear operation between 'x' and 'y'

Tags: java, math

Discover the linear operation between 'x' and 'y'...

This is my code:

```
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int x, int y) {
        return ( x / y ) * y;
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
x       y       EXPECTED RESULT     YOUR RESULT     DESCRIPTION 
1       1       1                   1           
2       2       2                   2           
919     648     1135                648             Mismatch
```

I can't imagine what code are suposed to be write.

Comment: It returns the highest multiple of `y` that is less than or equal to `x`.

Comment: not true @rgettman--1135 is not a multiple of 648.

Comment: @La-comadreja I'm not claiming that `1135` is a multiple of `648`.

Comment: Why were you expecting 1135? Neither integer maths nor conventional maths would give that result

Comment: @rgettman They were asking what the linear operation should be, not what their code is doing.

Comment: @La-comadreja `648` is the highest multiple of `648` that is less than or equal to `919`.

Comment: @rgettman the question is about making your result match the expected result.  Which the code doesn't.

Comment: @La-comadreja Well that was quite unclear.

Comment: Is there any information about the types of x and y? The answer depends on this

Comment: Puzzle(int x, int y), so x and y are `int`.

Comment: You wrote it's your implementation. Are x and y integers in the question as well?

Comment: Are you talking about www.codehunt.com?

Comment: You should give this a try: 
``public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int x, int y) {
        x = (x + y) + y;
        return x;
    }
} ``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x + (y / 3)
```

where x and y are integer types.  You need to think about why being integer types is so essential.

Comment: Even without integer division it'd just be x + floor(y/3).

Comment: right, but this is presumably basic syntax and may be an attempt to go into conceptual aspects of primitive types.  @BonzaiThePenguin the Java syntax is actually Math.floor(y/3) for the greatest integer less than y/3.

Answer (score 1):

For solution you need to take a closer look into word "linear operator": it means, that for `x` and `y` it returns something like `ax + by`, where `a` and `b` are constants. So:

a * 1 +  b * 1 = 1

a * 2 + b * 2 = 2 // may be removed as it's the same as the first line multiplied by 2

a * 919 + b * 648 = 1135

You can subtract first equality from the last multiplied by 648 and get

a * (919 - 648) = 1135 - 648 => a = 487 / 271 => b = 1 - a = (271 - 487) / 271 = -216 / 271

So, the resulting operator is

f(x, y) = 487/271 * x - 216/271 * y